# ColorRows Application.EnableEvents

Tags: excel, vba

I have conditional formatings Rule

```
=OR(CELL("col")=COLUMN(),CELL("row")=ROW())
```

and page event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
        Application.Calculate
    End If

End Sub
```

and function

```
Sub colorRows()
Dim rr As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set rr = Range("Table1[1]")
    ' take min and max
    val_min = 1000
    val_max = 0
    For Each rowR In rr
        firstLet = Asc(Left(rowR.Value2, 1)) Mod 56
        If firstLet < val_min Then val_min = firstLet
        If firstLet > val_max Then val_max = firstLet
    Next rowR
    val_mid = 0.5 * (val_min + val_max)
    For Each rgn In rr
    ' three color map min-mid-max
    ' min -> mid: green(99,190,123)-> yellow(255,235,132)
        firstLet = Asc(Left(rgn.Value, 1)) Mod 56
        If firstLet <= val_mid Then
            cr = 99 + (255 - 99) * (firstLet - val_min) / (val_mid - val_min)
            cg = 190 + (235 - 190) * (firstLet - val_min) / (val_mid - val_min)
            cb = 123 + (132 - 123) * (firstLet - val_min) / (val_mid - val_min)
        Else
    ' mid->max: yellow(255,235,132) -> red(248,105,107)
            cr = 255 + (248 - 255) * (firstLet - val_mid) / (val_max - val_mid)
            cg = 235 + (105 - 235) * (firstLet - val_mid) / (val_max - val_mid)
            cb = 132 + (107 - 132) * (firstLet - val_mid) / (val_max - val_mid)

        End If
        rgn.Interior.Color = RGB(cr, cg, cb)
        Range("Table1[[1]:[8]]").Rows(rgn.Row - 2).Interior.Color = RGB(cr, cg, cb)
        'With rowR.Characters(1, 1)
        '    .Font.Size = 12
        '    .Font.Bold = True
        '    .Font.ColorIndex = firstLet
        'End With

    Next rgn
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now im get
[image]

How to prevent color all rows as yellow after colorRows() complete?

Expected
[image]

Comment: It's difficult to account for your screenshot - CF coloring and non-CF coloring are independent, but CF always overrides non-CF coloring.  I applied row colors manually (should be no different from using code to do that) and it all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I try the colorRows sub individually, it works fine to fill the colors according to text at column A. It seems that the yellow color is your conditional formatting.

In excel, the conditional formatting will override the original color at the cells. Instead of looking at the colorRows, you should modify the conditional formatting.